# Email Newsletter not working properly in Gmail for Mobile Devices when using substitution tags

Tags: html, email

The email design shows a strange issue in **gmail for mobile devices.**
Happens in **safari when 'autofit' is enabled**

Since I know that gmail doesn't accept media queries, I have also added the tag at the bottom of the code, just before the body closing tag.

```html
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
```

Now the issue is that, I am adding substition tag in my email (title, firstname). When I receive the email for the first time in gmail, it looks good, but when the email is received for the second time, the design gets scrambled.

I have been trying for a fix

Ideally I would like to have the substitution tags and still have the same design when receiving twice

Any help/ideas would be much thankful.

**P.S** - If I don't use the substitution tag, I don't have this problem though. The email is sent from Sendgrid

Thanks

Comment: So your merge tags dosnt get shown in the mobile gmail version? You need !important behind display:none for it to work in gmail.

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup Thanks for your reply

The merge tags are indeed shown in the mobile gmail version
the problem is when i receive the same email again, the email design gets distorted and after huge amount of testing it is because of the customized merge tags used from sendgrid.

yes I have used !important in my code